# Using Row_number over partition by in SQL with Partitioning Feature Disabled

Tags: sql-server, oracle, window-functions

I want to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOME_COLUMN_NAME Order By SOME_COLUMN_NAME)`
in select SQL.

I am using both SQLServer as well as Oracle Database.

Does this require "Partitioning feature" to be enabled on Database?

UPDATE :-
i am using multiple Versions: SQL Server 2005 ,SQL Server 2008 R2 ,Oracle 11g

Comment: Did you try using the `row_number()` in your select?  Did it work?  Did you get an error?

Comment: For SQL Server: No! There is not even such option to configure. Even for Oracle I don't think its "Partitioning feature" has anything to do with `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @bluefeet Currently it works perfectly on my local but i am not sure of my client DB whether it has partitioning feature enabled or not.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic there is "partition by some_column_name" in SQL..not sure it has to do something with "partitioning feature"

Comment: @harrybvp This is a built in function of sql server starting with 2005, it is not something that is enabled/disabled

Comment: @bluefeet Ok for SQL Server .Is it same for Oracle?

Comment: @harrybvp There is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)` command and it works always. There is nothing you can configure to disable it. What I've ment is there is also nothing explicitly called `Partitioning feature` you can enable or disable.

Comment: @harrybvp And in Oracle there is something called `Partitioning feature` that can be disabled or enabled, but it got nothing to do with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) `

Comment: @Nenand sure there is - the OP is just confusing PARTITION BY and table partitioning, which of course are very different things.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for clearing my doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Partitioning Feature" is totally different from OLAP functions.

So, the answer is "YES" , you can use "Row_Number" with partitioning feature disabled.

Comment: Correct: "[PARTITION BY Divides the query result set into partitions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)"

Comment: The correct (ANSI SQL) term is "*window functions*" not "OLAP functions" (OLAP functions is the Microsoft term, analytical function would be the Oracle term).